# Pharo Smalltalk - How is variable scope in an Object achieved?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I'm experimenting in Pharo and I was wondering how class, instance variable scope is achieved.

More to the point, instance variables can be accessed by all the methods of that instance of a class, also class instance variables can be accessed by all the methods of the class and so on.

Where does the depth of this scope get defined in code? Can one see where and how this takes place, Smalltalk being fully Object Oriented?

Comment: Have you tried looking at how instance variables are accessed? It should be fairly obvious once you find out "where instance variables come from". ;-)

Comment: I literally have no idea where to look, conceptually since this is behaviour that permeates classes and instances I think it might be defined somewhere in ProtoObject, but I would appreciate exact directions to the place(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  presume you are in Pharo >= 4.0, in which case you have the so called `OpalCompiler`.

In `OpalCompiler`, the variable scope is reified (see `OCAbstractScope` and subclasses), the scope being used during semantic analysis of the Abstract Syntax Tree (see `OCASTSemanticAnalyzer`).

You now have an entry point, and should follow message senders, class refs, instance variable refs, ... from this starting point.